# qTip2 custom css issue

Tags: jquery, css, qtip

I'm trying to add my custom class on a qTip tooltip and some features don't work for a reason that I can't understand.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/qSr8B/) of what I want and it works.

And [here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qSr8B/252/) what I would like to do and it doesn't work.

I would like just to move the (position) part on my CSS for more clarity but somehow it doesn't work. Any idea why?

PS : disregard the `mouse:true` that `false` in the first one, it shouldn't affect anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
position: {
         target: 'mouse',
         adjust: {
             mouse: true
         } 
     } ;
```

This is not a valid css, you must add this to javascript file like in example #1.
In css no `target`, `adjust` or `mouse` properties exist.

Comment: Thanx you, i was suspecting it but was kinda lost in the whole thing to clearly see it :)